# how to remove a windows7 system font?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

the Windows7 system font is stopping me from installing a better font with the same name.

Removing it requires TrustedInstaller, but how can I be a TrustedInstaller ?

Answer (score 1):

As an administrator you can take ownership of the file - once you're the owner you can change the permissions to give yourself full control of the file then you can delete it.

Whether that's a good idea or not is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

1: change the system fonts as described here: [How to Change the Default Fonts in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1175-fonts-change.html)

2: Delete the old font as described here: [How to Delete Fonts in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1076-fonts-delete.html)

3: install the new font

4: repeat step 1 and change the system font to the newly installed font.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Font Substitutes in the registry](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1175-fonts-change.html)

Comment: This is an ancient post, but please consider expanding your answer to make it self-contained. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful. It's better to include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading. Thanks.